# Box to Box collision checking

Tags: c#, geometry, linear-algebra, collision-detection

I am trying to make a small 3d render with collision checking. I have been looking around for 3d box to box collision but haven't found one that checks all the boxes. I would like to make a OBB detection, one so where rotation isn't a problem. preferably have the collision detection return a normal vector for physics.

I have tried two methods. first being checking if each of the points of one box is inside the other. this doesn't work all the time if a rotation is present.
the second method is where I took the 12 lines that make up a cube and got the closest point to the center on those lines, then finally checked if those where within the cube. This second method has worked but I can't tell if it's my code or the way I did it. On paper this method seems like it would work but when testing it, it was inconsistent.

here is the current code for the collisions. It's using the second method. (in c#)

```
var ob1Rot = ob1.rotation;

Matrix4x4 m1rot = Matrix4x4.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(ob1Rot.Y, ob1Rot.X, ob1Rot.Z);
Matrix4x4.Invert(m1rot, out m1rot);
Matrix4x4 m1pos = Matrix4x4.CreateWorld(ob1.position, Vector3.UnitZ, Vector3.UnitY);
for (int i = 0; i < collidingLines.Length; i += 2)
{
    var center = mainCol.position;

    var point = GetClosestPointOnLineSegment(points[collidingLines[i]], points[collidingLines[i + 1]], center);

    var p = Vector3.Transform(Vector3.Transform(point, m1pos),m1rot);

    if (Math.Abs(p.X) < mainCol.size.X)
    {
        if (Math.Abs(p.Y) < mainCol.size.Y)
        {
            if (Math.Abs(p.Z) < mainCol.size.Z)
            {
                touched = true;

                var facePoints = new List<Vector3>();
                var normal = new Vector3();
                var closest = Vector3.Zero;
                for (int c = 0; c < defaultColliderFaces.Length; c+=4)
                {
                    var middle =(
                        
                        (collider.points[defaultColliderFaces[c]] +
                        collider.points[defaultColliderFaces[c+1]] +
                        collider.points[defaultColliderFaces[c+2]] +
                        collider.points[defaultColliderFaces[c+3]] ) / 4

                        );
                    if (Vector3.Distance(middle, point) < Vector3.Distance(closest, point))
                    {
                        closest = middle;
                        normal = Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Cross(collider.points[defaultColliderFaces[c]], collider.points[defaultColliderFaces[c + 2]]));
                    }
                }

                Touch t;
                    t = new Touch(mainCol, collider, point, -normal);
                    if (currentTouch != -1)
                    mainCol.touchingColliders[currentTouch] = t;
                else
                    mainCol.touchingColliders.Add(t);
                //var b = new Touch(collider, mainCol, point2, normal2);
                    //b.normal =
                if (currentTouchB != -1)
                    collider.touchingColliders[currentTouchB] = t;
                else
                    collider.touchingColliders.Add(t);


                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a few classes, so sorry for making this hard to understand.
each of the

the defaultColliderFaces is a array of ints corresponding to the indexes of the points of a cube to make 6 faces
mainCol is a collider class. this corresponds to ob1.
collider is a collider class. this corresponds to ob2.
a "Touch" is a class that stores two of the collider class as well as a colliding point and a normal vector.

```
int[] defaultColliderFaces =
{
    0,1,2,3,
    0,3,7,4,
    0,4,5,1,
    5,1,2,6,
    5,4,7,6,
    7,6,2,3
};
```

```
points = new Vector3[]
{
    new Vector3(size.X, size.Y, size.Z) ,
    new Vector3(-size.X, size.Y, size.Z) ,
    new Vector3(-size.X, size.Y, -size.Z),
    new Vector3(size.X, size.Y, -size.Z) ,
    new Vector3(size.X, -size.Y, size.Z) ,
    new Vector3(-size.X, -size.Y, size.Z),
    new Vector3(-size.X, -size.Y, -size.Z),
    new Vector3(size.X, -size.Y, -size.Z)
};
```

```
int[] collidingLines =
{
    0,1,
    1,2,
    2,3,
    3,0,

    0,4,
    3,7,
    2,6,
    1,5,

    4,5,
    5,6,
    6,7,
    7,4
};
```